# Finding Factorials with Gamma

Tags: code-golf, number, factorial, floating-point

## Introduction

We know that the factorial notation is valid for all natural numbers. However, Euler had extended it for all positive real numbers, as well as for complex numbers by defining a function, which is known as the Gamma Function. It is represented by Γ.

## Challenge

You will be given a non-negative floating point number, say 'n' (with a maximum of 2 decimal places in it), and you need to output the factorial of that number correct to at least 3 decimal places. Assume all inputs to be valid, and n <= 7.

Now talking about Gamma function, there is an integral which can be used to find the value of any factorial. You may choose to use it. You can find more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). The Gamma function is recursive in nature. One important property, which would probably be useful to you is:

Γ(n) = (n-1)! , which means that, n! = Γ(n) . n

Also note that we really do not need to know Γ(n) for all values of n. For instance, look at the number 4.5 - we can write its factorial as:

```
4.5! = 4.5 * 3.5 * 2.5 * 1.5 * 0.5! = 59.0625 * 0.5!
```

So here we need only the value of 0.5! , which means the value of Γ(1.5). Also, similarly, we can find the factorial of any decimal if we know the values of factorials of numbers between 0 and 1, i.e, values of gamma function of numbers between 1 and 2. You need it, so that is why there is a table below for your help:

[image: Table For Values of Gamma Function]

Using this table, we can see that 0.5!, i.e, the value of Γ(1.5) = 0.88623, which gives our result: (4.5)! = 59.0625 * 0.88623 = 52.3429594 , which is indeed a good result. Similarly,

```
(5.7)! = (5.7)*(4.7)*(3.7)*(2.7)*(1.7)*(0.7)! = 454.97457 * 0.90864 = 413.408093
```

Also, if you do not wish to use the table for calculating the gamma function, here is a simple integral to help you out:

[image: Integral for Gamma Function]

Remember that you can provide your answers only up to 3 decimal places if you want to. But the value should have minimum error. Like, +- 0.003 is acceptable.

You are free to decide in what way you want to compute the factorial - whether by the integral, or by the table, or using any other method.

## Examples

Please note that here the answer is correct to 3 decimal places.

```
2.4 -> 2.981
3.9 -> 20.667
2.59 -> 3.675
1.7 -> 1.545
0.5 -> 0.886
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

Comment: Please note that this challenge was posted on sandbox and people decided that this is not a dupe because this challenge allows built ins.

Comment: Can we output as a rational number (i.e fraction)? Like, `8275608925237915/2251799813685248` for the 3rd test case.

Comment: Sorry but as per the rules, decimal answers only

Comment: I interpreted "3 decimal places" to mean the leading digits, so "the relative error is `< 1/1000`". But your examples seems to imply 3 digits after the decimal point, which would be a relative error of `1/5040000` for `7!` which is more accurate than your table. You can almost see this in your example of `5.7!` where the correct result `413.40752` only juuust rounds to `413.408`. It should be easy to find examples where it fails. Please clarify what you mean

Comment: @TonHospel well I meant 3 places after decimal.Also the table is very unlikely to fail.

Comment: Aww, I was about to extend Whispers' factorial notation to cover the gamma function, and it'll look like cheating if I add an answer now.

Comment: Since all built-in solutions are being combined in a single post, I consider this a duplicate of the Gamma challenge.

Comment: I think that near `7!` the table is actually very likely to fail for 3 digits after `.`. And even if it didn't, you don't want to have to think about `1000.000499` vs `1000.000501` so you should really have asked for accuracy as a max absolute error

Answer (score 1):

## Community wiki for built-in solutions

This answer is intended to collect answers that are simply [built-ins](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14443). It's a community wiki, so anybody can edit in without approval. Go ahead and include any **built-in only** solution here, following [xnor's proposal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11218) and according to [our consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14397).

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/xv87hdpVHTWuyHjXMUdC1U3jUMBfEjfz/30jPREfBWM9SR8FIzxRIGuqZ6ygY6JkCAA)

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/) , 1 byte

```
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Ff9rcnGlJmfkK6QpGOmZWv4HAA)

### [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 1 byte

```
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f9f8f9/Iz1TSwA)

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2 bytes

```
.!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X0/x/38jPVNLAA)

### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 9 bytes

```r
factorial
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z8tMbkkvygzMed/mkZxcmKehqYml5GeCZexniWQNrXkMtQz5zLQM/0PAA)

### [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/), 2 bytes

```
|F
```

[Try and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7CF&i=8&a=1)

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 3 bytes

```
#!&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78r8FVbaRnoqNgrGepo2CkZwokDfXMdRQM9Exr/yv@19TXDyjKzCv5DwA)

Comment: `!` is not a function in Mathematica, it is an operator, and hence is not a valid submission.

Comment: @totallyhuman Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), `-p` 40 bytes

Very slow. One run takes about 13 minutes for me.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$\=5e8**++$_/$_;$\/=1+$'/$_ for//..5e8}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxtYw1VxLS1tbJV5fJd5aJUbf1lBbRR3IVkjLL9LX19MDytdW//9vqmf@L7@gJDM/r/i/bsF/XV9TPQM9QwMA)

The TIO link uses `1e7` instead of `5e8` to avoid timeouts and is therefore not accurate enough

## Old version, `-p` 60 bytes, not accurate enough

Uses a Stirling approximation. But even with the first correction term that is pretty inaccurate for small n. So instead I approximate `(n+2)!/(n+2)/(n+1)`.

Notice that I don't bother trying to get the first 3 digits right, but the relative error seems to properly be `< 0.001` in the range `[0, 7]`. E.g. `0!` outputs `0.999481433067179` which would be `1.000` if rounded to 3 digits.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=(($_+=2)/exp 1)**$_*(2+1/6/$_)/$_/($_-1)*sqrt$_*atan2 1,0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcopDsAgEEDRqyAQLGVNwHGEnmGCQDRpgAKip@8U8dX7vYw7IFJIjFGQyXNT3k4cF4KCYF46Ew0FvjN7UBvmM9a2vHL1xB0WMX6tr6vViaqjOoO22tkf)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 1 byte

```apl
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRFIKVgpGfClaZgrGfJBWKbgihDPXMgaaBnCgA)

In APL, the factorial primitive has always included the entire domain of the gamma function.

Comment: I've created a [community wiki answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157445/59487) for built-in only answers following [our consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14397/59487) and [xnor's proposal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/should-we-combine-answers-where-the-same-code-works-in-many-different-languages/11218#11218). You can transfer your solution there if you want, but feel free to keep it as-is otherwise.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, this also works in J.